# How to get the content of error message from API with axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, axios, try-catch

I was working on a API error handling, with by using catch error method if can only get these data but not the actual message from my API.

```js
.catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      });
```

and all I can get is :

> Blob {size: 14, type: 'application/json'}
> size: 14
> type: "application/json"
> [[Prototype]]: Blob

If I access API directly I can't get the message such as:

> "{"detail":"Invalid signature"}"

Is there a way to get the actual message that I wrote in API in react?

It's not the API's problem BTW.
And surprisingly, I did get the content length.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.